# Reading integers in .txt file and store in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I know this question might be answered many times. However, I still cannot solve this specific problem.

Basically I have a .txt file with the following format.

```
String Integer String
```

For example,

```
la 789 ferrari
turbo 560 porsche
veyron 987 bugatti
sls 563 benz
dbs 510 aston
```

How can I read the file line by line and store the numbers/integers ONLY into arraylist?
Thank you!

Comment: But have you tried at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more full Java-esque solution, using Java 7 ... for fun.

Main.java

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main
{
    private static final InputFileParser inputFileParser = new InputFileParser();
    private static final EntryNumberExtractor extractor = new EntryNumberExtractor();
    private static final String FILENAME = "input-file.txt";

    public static void main(String... args) 
    {
        List<Entry> entries = inputFileParser.parse(FILENAME);
        List<Integer> extractedIntegers = extractor.extract(entries);

        System.out.println("Entries: ");
        prettyPrintListItems(entries);

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Entry numbers: ");
        prettyPrintListItems(extractedIntegers);
    }

    private static <T> void prettyPrintListItems(List<T> list)
    {
        for (T item : list)
        {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}
```

InputFileParser.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class InputFileParser
{
    public List<Entry> parse(String filename)
    {
        List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        File f = new File(filename);
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));)
        {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                String[] components = line.split(" ");
                entries.add(new Entry(components[0], Integer.parseInt(components[1]), components[2]));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return entries;
    }
}
```

EntryNumberExtractor.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EntryNumberExtractor
{
    public List<Integer> extract(List<Entry> entries)
    {
        List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Entry e : entries) 
        {
            integers.add(e.getNumber());
        }
        return integers;
    }
}
```

Entry.java

```
public class Entry
{
    private String model;
    private int number;
    private String company;

    public Entry(String model, int number, String company)
    {
        this.model = model;
        this.number = number;
        this.company = company;
    }

    public Integer getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "model: " + model + ", number: " + number + ", company: " + company;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow very nice effort! however, when I am compiling in terminal, it returns an error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at InputFileParser.parse(InputFileParser.java:20)
 at Main.main(Main.java:11)

Comment: It's likely due to the format of your input file. Double check that your contents are exactly as you posted above. I've included the code so that you could use it as a working example and be able to debug into and also recognize it's weaknesses where you may need to add extra error handling (if the line cannot be separated twice by spaces, for example).

Comment: yeah the .txt file is exactly like I have posted above with only 1 separate space. I have also tried the other example answer and it gives the same compile error too. (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Comment: If you're getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at one of the lines that indexes the components of the line, then that means the line that was read into the program could not be separated (by spaces) into that # of components. For example, if you've got `String sampleString = "hello world"` and you execute `sampleString.split(" ")[2]`, you will get the same exception, because you couldn't separate the `sampleString` into 3 pieces.

Comment: Drop a debug marker down around the line you're seeing problems with and have a look at the value of the components array. That should give you a hint.

Comment: over the last hour, I have tried to debug but failed and now I am still very confused of the out of bound exception problem. is it possible for a little bit more guidance from you please?

Comment: Sure. You said above the .txt file is exactly like what you have posted with only 1 separate space. Where is this extra space? Is it on it's own line?

Comment: oh sorry what I mean is that in between the `la 789` as well as `789 ferrari`is separate by a single space. sorry for the confusion..

Comment: Ah, okay. Keep in mind, if there's an empty blank line after your data, that could break this particular sample. When I add one, I get: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at com.tester.InputFileParser.parse(InputFileParser.java:22)
at com.tester.Main.main(Main.java:13)`

Comment: oh i see! I never know that an empty blank line in the .txt file would make such a huge runtime error for me. You saved my day! thank you very much!

Comment: No problem at all! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<int> list = new ArrayList<int>();

try {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    String line = br.readLine();

    while(line != null)
    {
         String[] tokens = line.Split(" ");
         list.Add(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]));
         line = br.readLine()

    }
catch(Exception e)
{
    //Probably a conversation exception or a index out of bounds exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read each line and split the line string by space, retrieve the number and store it in array list

Comment: This is perhaps more fit to be a comment